# Как редактировать каждый элемент в списке

Tags: python

Во первых прошу простить за вопрос но я голову сломал над ответом и не смог найти...

```
a = ['35.65 usd', '53.25 usd', '352.75 usd']
```

> Нужно сначала убрать "usd" затем перевести на российский курс а потом поставить "rub" в конец каждого элемента

Comment: воспользоваться методом `split`, перевести строка в число с плавающей точкой, вычислить курс

Comment: Что именно из этого не получилось? Какие были попытки?

Comment: Сначала реши задачу для одного элемента, а потом уже думай, как применять ко всем

Comment: Спасибо @ClarkDevlin ,  я решил задачу

Comment: @ClarkDevlin что делать если выходит ошибка ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15,65' похоже он точку принимает за плавающую цифру а запятую нет

Comment: Поменять запятую на точку очевидно!

Answer (score 1):

> Ответ

```
a = ['35.65 usd' , '32.65 usd' , '325.65 usd']
d = []
kurs: int = input("Введите курс: ")
for i in a:
    b = i.split()
    b.remove('usd')
    for x in b:
        v = float(x)
        d.append(v * int(kurs))
    print(d)
```